# LinearLayout in RemoteViews not cropping ImageView

Tags: android, android-widget, android-linearlayout

I have a n app widget that is pretty much working, with one quirk.  I've got a LinearLayout in the widget, and I can add rows of my data to it just fine.  There doesn't seem to be any obvious way for me to tell how big the linear layout is and if a given row will fit, so I just add the entire data set (since it isn't very large).  The text in my layout gets cropped at the bottom, which is what I'd expect.  However, the ImageView next to it is not being cropped, but is instead being scaled.  It, frankly, looks goofy.

If there's a way for me to tell if a row will fit in my LinearLayout, that would be great.  If there's a way I can tell it to just crop my image, that would be fine too.  This is what the cropping looks like.

The layout for the rows I'm adding (if there's a goof here, it's probably from the anonymization I applied):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="28sp"
        android:layout_height="28sp"
        android:src="@drawable/check_off"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:minHeight="28sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkbox"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: The container for the rows is just a simple LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_items"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/logo"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_background"/>
```

Comment: it can be better if u add ur main layout info. in which u r adding

Comment: I added the LinearLayout here, although it's pretty boring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that giving the RelativeLayout that corresponds to the row a specific height (30sp, for this layout) instead of "wrap_content" fixed the problem.  The image now crops correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a scaletype to your ImageView:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

or

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

or any of the other options listed here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: I tried doing that, but it didn't seem to fix the problem.  I actually just figured out the fix for this, which was to make the row a fixed height.